# All karma test fails after a while

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I am testing a angular service in karma and it works at first, but after a while the tests fail and i need to restart karma.

The error message I get is:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: Score2Provider <- Score2

I run karma with the following conf:

```
module.exports = function(config){
  config.set({

    basePath : './',

    files : [
      'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
      'bower_components/lodash/dist/lodash.js',
      'bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
      'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
      'tests/main-mock.js',
      'client/js/score2.js',
      'tests/*.js',
    ],

    autoWatch : true,

    frameworks: ['jasmine'],

    browsers : ['Chrome'],

    plugins : [
            'karma-chrome-launcher',
            'karma-jasmine',
            ],
  });
};
```

I'm running it on a Windows 8.1 machine.

And as I said, it works at first but after a few minutes all tests fail with that error message.
Has anyone else got this problem and does anybody know how to fix it?

Comment: Score2Provider is not available "second" time. How do you run the tests second time ? What are the differences between the first run and second run ?

Comment: Yes, I know. Since I use autoWatch it runs again every time I update a file. And after a while it breaks, but if I then restart karma it works again, so I don't think it's an error in my code. It's like the watch somehow can't read the file properly

Comment: I am actually suggesting problems in the way your are setting this up/ Are you using your Grunt/Gulp ? If yes post relevant sections from there. If not tell us how you invoke the test.

Comment: I'm not currently using any build tool. I just run `karma start` and it watches my files and reruns the tests when they change.

Comment: My guess is that one of the karma dependencies are not working on Windows 8.1. e.g. Socket.io had some issues on Win 8. Your Karma.conf are fine although based on what you describe you should add `singleRun: false`. If you are skeptical about anything your are doing simply run this somewhere other than win 8 to test.

Comment: Also try adding `--log-level LOG_DEBUG` to the command line when you run. It may reveal anything fishy.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to clean cache before $httpBackend.flush() in AngularJs Unit Test?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19510469/how-to-clean-cache-before-httpbackend-flush-in-angularjs-unit-test)

Answer (score 0):

`Score2` is a service, so it depends on a module. The module can be changed during the tests due to:

- Injecting another module with the same name
- Declaring another module with the same name
- Escaping issue while copying the updated files
- Reorganizing the `beforeEach` method source order

Cleanup any global variables in an `afterEach` to prevent this.

**References**

- [AngularJS Error Reference: $injector - unpr (Unknown Provider)](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr)
- [Angular JS - Unit Testing - Services](http://www.benlesh.com/2013/06/angular-js-unit-testing-services.html)
- [AngularJS Issue #2767 - proposed: implicit namespacing](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2767)